# Uncaught More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: post

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to follow [this basic Ember.js tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ga99hMi7wfY#at=329) but having no luck with the "posts" model. I have everything set up according to the demonstration, however I am getting the error:

`Uncaught More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: post`

Since this is the first time I've ever worked with an Ember.js app, I honestly have no clue what this means. Any help (literally anything) would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('posts', function() {
        this.resource('post', { path:'post_id'})
    });
    this.resource('about');
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Post.find();
    }
})

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    intro: DS.attr('string'),
    extended: DS.attr('string'),
    publishedAt: DS.attr('date')
});

App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
        id: 1,
        title: "Rails in Omakase",
        author: "d2h",
        publishedAt: new Date('12-27-2012'),
        intro: "Blah blah blah blah",
        extended: "I have no clue what extended means"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        title: "Second post",
        author: "second author",
        publishedAt: new Date('1-27-2012'),
        intro: "second intro",
        extended: "Second extended"
    }];
```

And here is the html for the posts.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <table class='table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
                </thead>
                {{#each model}}
                <tr><td>
                    {{#linkTo 'post' this}}{{title}} <small class='muted'>by {{author}}</small>{{/linkTo}}
                </td></tr>
                {{/each}}
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                {{outlet}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2> by {{author}} <small class="muted">{{publishedAt}}</small></h2>

    <hr>

    <div class="intro">
        {{intro}}
    </div>

    <div class="below-the-fold">
        {{extended}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you meant to have a route specified.

```
this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('post', { path:'/post/:post_id'})
});
```

The error sounds like you are passing something like `post/12` and you don't have a dynamic segment specified(written as `:post_id`) The `:` is the important point that specifies a dynamic segment.

Taken from the [Ember.js documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/)

Comment: I wonder why it is working as expected on the video tutorial, could it be a newer version of Ember?

Comment: Just to add to this, `resource` was deprecated in Ember 2.x. Newer applications should use `route` in place of it.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works.

However, given where the op is in the example, the more correct fix is to leave the following alone:

```
this.resource('posts');
```

and add this below it:

```
this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id'});
```

Comment: This did not help me directly, but it point me to the place where i had the route twice ;)